# Testing sum of two parameters different from 0 on a given interval in regression

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, regression-coefficients

I have been struggling on a problem from the past few days, and I hoped you could help. I have estimated an OLS regression model of the form:

$Y=\beta_0 + \beta_1 x + \beta_2 ln(x) + ...$

$\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ are significant, and have opposite signs.

$\beta_1 x = 0.0053$

$\beta_2 ln(x) = -0.2464$

When I plot their joint effect, I obtain this plot ($x$ is bounded between 1 and a 100).

[image: Joint effect of x and ln(x)]

I would like to show with a nice statistical test that an increase in x leads to a significant decrease in Y from 1 to 50, and that it has no significant overall impact afterward. Is there a way to do that?